# split a string based on some pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which looks like this

```
text = HybridHello.x /usr/lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib64/crti.o /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/trace_init.o /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/crtbeginT.o /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/initmp.o /opt/cray/atp/1.4.1/lib//libAtpSigHandler.a /opt/cray/mpt/5.3.5/xt/seastar/mpich2-pgi/109/lib/libmpich_pgi.a /opt/cray/mpt/5.3.5/xt/seastar/mpich2-pgi/109/lib/libmpl.a /opt/cray/pmi/2.1.4-1.0000.8596.15.1.ss/lib64/libpmi.a /opt/cray/portals/2.2.0-1.0301.26633.6.9.ss/lib64/libportals.a /usr/lib/alps/libalpslli.a /usr/lib/alps/libalpsutil.a /usr/lib64/libpthread.a /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/libpgmp.a /usr/lib64/libpthread.a /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/nonuma.o /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/libnspgc.a /opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/libpgc.a /usr/lib64/libpthread.a /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/libgcc.a /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/libgcc_eh.a /usr/lib64/libc.a /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/crtend.o /usr/lib64/crtn.o
```

I want to split the contents of this string based upon first  '/' and then a continuing space rejecting the first *.* file name (in this case HybridHello.x) for example -

```
/usr/lib64/crt1.o
/usr/lib64/crti.o
/opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/trace_init.o
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/crtbeginT.o
```

and likewise.

I have a little experience in regular expression but that too in perl. Could someone please advise?

Comment: Do you really need regex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is an overkill for this Job. You can use `str.split` and slice out the first element from your list

**Implementation**

```
for files in text.split()[1:]:
    print files
```

**Output**

```
/usr/lib64/crt1.o
/usr/lib64/crti.o
/opt/pgi/11.9.0/linux86-64/11.9/lib/trace_init.o
....
```

**Note**

A Regex equivalant of it might be `re.split("\s+", test)[1:]` or `re.findall("[^\s]+", test)[1:]` , but it should not be evident that its unnecessary